# Conditional in bash for concatenating multiple files

Tags: bash

I am working with multiple files that I would like to concatenate prior further processing down the pipeline. Typically there are 1 to 3 different pair of files that I need to concatenate, but occasionally there are more than three pairs. I would like to tweak my script with conditional so instead of having absolute number, I just pass a conditional (either 1 or greater than 1 files) to concatenate. I was wondering if anyone can give me a hint:

```
if [ $no_lanes -eq "1" ]; then
        fq_align_1=$lane1_pair1
        fq_align_2=$lane1_pair2
fi

if [ $no_lanes -eq "2"  ]; then
        cat $lane1_pair1 $lane2_pair1 > "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        cat $lane1_pair2 $lane2_pair2 > "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
        fq_align_1="$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        fq_align_2="$sampleID"_cat2.fq
fi

if [ $no_lanes -eq "3" ]; then
        cat $lane1_pair1 $lane2_pair1 $lane3_pair1 > "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        cat $lane1_pair2 $lane2_pair2 $lane3_pair3 > "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
        fq_align_1="$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        fq_align_2="$sampleID"_cat2.fq
fi ....
```

Comment: Please read on what makes [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: My input is raw fastq data (a text-based format for storing DNA sequence). I've got one file containing data in forward direction and one file containing data in reverse direction. Occasionally, there are more than 1 pair (F & R) that I need to concatenate all forward data together and reverse data together.

Comment: How do you get the filenames? if only you had used arrays, the answer would be trivially straightforward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a simple `for` loop should work.

```
cat "$lane1_pair1" > "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
cat "$lane1_pair2" > "$sampleID"_cat2.fq

for (( n=2; n<=no_lanes; n++ )) {
        pair1var=lane${n}_pair1
        pair2var=lane${n}_pair2
        cat "${!pair1var}" >> "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        cat "${!pair2var}" >> "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
}

fq_align_1="$sampleID"_cat1.fq
fq_align_2="$sampleID"_cat2.fq
```

Edit: Fixed the variable indirection in the loop. For some reason I was thinking that I was crafting filenames in the loop. However it's actually crafting variable names. Doing that requies a slight indirection using the ${!...} expansion.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Naeglaria, glad I could help. Feel free to officially accept this answer if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: I am not able to cast my vote for your answer as I don't have enough credit!
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Naeglaria, I don't mean the vote button. I mean the little checkmark you see underneath the downvote button. But if it doesn't work, don't worry about it.

Comment: @Naeglaria I just realized that I made a mistake with the name crafting in the loop. I've just edited it. Thanks for the accept btw.

Comment: Use more quotes. Fix the syntax errors (no spaces around `=`). Don't use indirection, use an array instead.

Comment: Also, you could use file descriptors and put the redirection after the `for` loop so as to not uselessly re-open the same files several times. The first `cat` are a bit weird too.